# market tickers in dart programming language

Tags: dart, puppeteer

I was trying to fetch market tickers from Google Finance but I am getting the same value over time. Below is my code, any fix? Its giving same output $2,254.84 again and again.

```
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:puppeteer/puppeteer.dart' as pp;

void main() async {
  var launch = await pp.puppeteer.launch(
    executablePath: "/usr/bin/brave-browser",
  );
  print(await launch.version);

  var stocks_nasdaq = ["GOOG", "MSFT", "APPL", "TESLA"];
  var page = await launch.newPage();

  while (true) {
    for (var asset in stocks_nasdaq) {
      await page.goto("https://www.google.com/finance/quote/$asset:NASDAQ");
      var kk = ["c_p", "24h", "p_year"].iterator;

      var aa = ((await page.$$eval("div.P6K39c",
          'function (el) { var eee=[];for(var a=0;a<el.length;a++){eee[a]=el[a].innerHTML; }    return eee; }')));
      for (var a in aa) {
        if (a.contains("\$")) {
          kk.moveNext();
          print({
            asset: {kk.current: a}
          });
        }
      }

      io.sleep(Duration(seconds: 10));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Output: 'HeadlessChrome/88.1.20.110 {GOOG: {c_p: $2,254.84}}
{GOOG: {24h: $2,266.00 - $2,306.60}}
{GOOG: {p_year: $1,209.71 - $2,306.60}}
{MSFT: {c_p: $255.59}}
{MSFT: {24h: $257.73 - $259.93}}
{MSFT: {p_year: $166.11 - $259.93}}
{GOOG: {c_p: $2,254.84}}
{GOOG: {24h: $2,266.00 - $2,306.60}}
{GOOG: {p_year: $1,209.71 - $2,306.60}}

Comment: The API for Google Finance is closed so you should properly try find another API which actually can be used since what you are trying to do is not a very stable solution. I found this article which comes with some alternative solutions: https://rapidapi.com/blog/google-finance-api-alternatives/ . Another solution is to make some integration to the Google Sheet API which has a function which provides some kind of access to some of the numbers from Google Finance.

Comment: @buruguanudeep consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67118433/edit) your post to show that output in a more readable manner.